# Ошибка инициализации Tessnet2

Tags: c#, tesseract

В проекте использую tessnet2_32.dll. Не могу понять, почему не происходит инициализация:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(<изображение>);
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();

ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

try
{

    ocr.Init(<путь к tessdata>, "eng", false);
}
catch ()
{   
}

List<Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (Word word in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{word.Confidence} : {word.Text}" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Tessdata взял [отсюда](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata).
Приложение закрывается на методе Init. Обертка в try не помогает - реакции нет

Comment: Наверно этот вопрос стоит задавать автору данного творения, а не сторонним людям, многие из которых впервые видят и слышат про эту библиотек?

Comment: Tessnet2 устарел. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract

Comment: @aepot Увы, это не меняет того факта, что данная библиотека мало кому известна из рядовых пользователей, что сводит к минимуму шанс на получение ответа, ибо это может быть как проблема в самой библиотеке, так и проблема в ее использовании, версии и так далее и только автор должен знать наверняка что тут не так.

Comment: @aepot, большое спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хм, гугление выдает статью на хабре об использовании этой библиотеки сразу же. Да, библиотека старая, но думал, что не такая неизвестная)

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Вы получили за этот день хоть один ответ? Я что-то не вижу. Коммент выше не ответ, а обходной путь, который говорит, что есть новое. Так что извините, но за 4 года на SO, я понял, что люди не будут за вас искать информацию, они лишь возьмут первую ссылку гугла, попытают счастье и забьют на вопрос. По этому я и говорил, что вы вряд-ли тут с таким вопросом найдете решение, ибо мало кто захочет искать за вас, пробовать и пытаться воспроизвести, увы, таковы реалии, особенно, когда библиотека не  популярна для большинства (метка с 30 вопросами тому доказательство).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я тоже не первый год на форумах (хотя и не был на SO), поэтому не ждал того, о чём Вы написали. Была возможность, что кто-то именно с этим столкнулся. Повторюсь, я понял, что библиотека устарела - и отлаживать эту ошибку уже бессмысленно -> было дано верное другое направление. ЗА что благодарен

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Ну SO это не форум, а база вопрос-ответ, где сообщество собирает полезное, ценное для будущих читателей (а не только для самих себя). Ценен ли ваш вопрос для SO?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, наверное, человек, наткнувшись на этот вопрос, поймёт, что стоит использовать указанную библиотеку?

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Ох не думаю... Проголосовал за закрытие, уж извините, пользы я для SO от него не вижу.

Comment: Да, закрывайте всё - только с 5+ ответами по 100 голосов стоит оставлять вопросы. ;)